# Подскажите как выставить фиксированное расстояние между слайдами. Чтобы соседние слайды выглядывали

Tags: slick.js

В документации есть пример, только вот у меня так не срабатывает - на экране один слайд и хоть ты тресни)))

```js
$('.slider-1').slick({
infinite: true,
/*  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,*/
centerMode: true,
centerPadding: '20px',
slidesToShow: 1,
appendArrows: $('.arrow-1'),
prevArrow: '<a href="#" class="slick-arrow slick-prev wow fadeOutLeft infinite data-wow-delay="3s""><img src="../img/icons/left-arrow.png"></a>',
nextArrow: '<a href="#" class="slick-arrow slick-next wow fadeOutRight infinite data-wow-delay="3s""><img src="../img/icons/right-arrow.png"></a>'
});
});
```

нужно сделать так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а по факту не получатся и выходит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста куда копать??((

Comment: создайте ваш [mcve] с html, js и css

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден.: `ariableWidth: true`,